# Convert Spring Integration Cafe demo from xml config to Java 8 DSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I try to convert the integration cafe demo to Java 8 DSL, there are some existing examples in the official [Spring Integration Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples).

I want to combine all the good parts of these examples.

- Java 8 DSL instead of XML
- AMQP to slipt the workflow in smaller flows.
- Using Jackson to handle the payload in JSON.

The codes(not work as expected, some issues) are [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-playground/tree/master/integration-cafe-amqp).

In the official XML samples, it is easy to set up a request/reply channel in Amqp gateway. But go to Java 8 DSL, the options are missing.

And when the application, it will complain "reply channel or output channel is required".

BTW, is there any better option to debug/unit testing the Spring integration application?

**Update 1: confused when I was writing the flow of  coldDrinks flow.**

The XML is from the original [cafe-amqp](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/applications/cafe/cafe-amqp/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/amqp/cafeDemo-amqp-baristaCold-xml.xml) project.

```xml
<!-- To receive an AMQP Message from a Queue, and respond to its reply-to address, configure an inbound-gateway. -->
    <int-amqp:inbound-gateway
        id="coldDrinksBarista"
        request-channel="coldJsonDrinks"
        queue-names="cold-drinks"
        connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" />

    <int:chain input-channel="coldJsonDrinks">
        <int:json-to-object-transformer type="org.springframework.integration.samples.cafe.OrderItem"/>
        <int:service-activator method="prepareColdDrink">
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.samples.cafe.xml.Barista"/>
        </int:service-activator>
        <int:object-to-json-transformer content-type="text/x-json"/>
    </int:chain>
```

How to convert this into Java DSL effectively. **I added my thoughts inline**

```java
 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow coldDrinksFlow(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("coldDrinks")
                .handle(
                        Amqp.outboundGateway(amqpTemplate)
                                .exchangeName(TOPIC_EXCHANGE_CAFE_DRINKS)
                                .routingKey(ROUTING_KEY_COLD_DRINKS)
                )
                .log("coldDrinksFlow")
                .channel(preparedDrinksChannel())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow coldDrinksBaristaFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Barista barista) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Amqp.inboundGateway(connectionFactory, QUEUE_COLD_DRINKS)
                        .configureContainer(
                                c -> c.receiveTimeout(10000)
                        )// If setup replyChannel the below `handle` is not worked as expected.


                )
                .handle(OrderItem.class, (payload, headers) -> (Drink) barista.prepareColdDrink(payload))
//If adding a channel here, the flow will NOT return back the `coldDrinksFlow` will cause another exception, "its requiresReply is set to true..."
                .get();
    }
```

In my before experience, I would like to break the whole flow by the protocols(HTTP, FTP, etc) as edges(inbound at the beginning and outbound as the end) in small flows. The inbound/outbound gateway is easy to set it to work without setting a reply channel etc, it should reply by default through the original route using its built-in protocols instead of channels. In my [inboundGateway RSocket example](https://github.com/hantsy/rsocket-sample/blob/master/integration/server/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L40-L50), I don't set a reply channel there, but the message returns to the roscket routes and receive by the [client side(outboudGateway)](https://github.com/hantsy/rsocket-sample/blob/master/integration/client/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L38-L49).

**Update:** Finally it works, check [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-playground/blob/master/cafe-integration-amqp-dsl/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java). An issue I encountered here when trying to use Amqp to send and receive object message, the are some class cast exception thrown, the *TypeId* in headers is NOT changed when using `handle` etc `MessageHandler`, have to transform bwteen json/object like the xml based [cafe-amqp](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/applications/cafe/cafe-amqp/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/amqp/cafeDemo-amqp-baristaCold-xml.xml) did to make it finally work. What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There is already an official Java DSL sample in that repo: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/dsl/cafe-dsl.

Yes, there is no an AMQP variant, but if you follow an `Amqp` factory from `spring-integration-amqp`, that should not be too hard to convert that XML config to Java DSL.

Not sure what is that "bad option" for testing you use, but in the `spring-integration-test` we provide enough utils to simplify flows testing: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/testing.html#testing

**UPDATE**

Your problem is here:

```
<int-amqp:outbound-gateway
    id="coldDrinksBarista"
    request-channel="coldDrinks"
    reply-channel="preparedJsonDrinks"
    exchange-name="cafe-drinks"
    routing-key="drink.cold"
    amqp-template="amqpTemplate" />
```

where your config:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow coldDrinksFlow(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("coldDrinks")
            .handle(
                    Amqp.outboundGateway(amqpTemplate)
                            .exchangeName(TOPIC_EXCHANGE_CAFE_DRINKS)
                            .routingKey(ROUTING_KEY_COLD_DRINKS)
            )
            .get();
}
```

doesn't have a similar `replyChannel` part. That why you get that `reply channel or output channel is required` because you send from the `route` which does not expect any replies. Probably you just haven't finished to design your application for the whole logic...

Comment: I was using this dsl sample as base and compared to `cafe-amqp` to when I created this sample, I am not sure how amqp works with the integration channel, the xml versioned cafe-amqp is easy to understand.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer, please.

Comment: I see, the problem is there is no `request-channel` or `reply-chnannel` related methods on `Amqp.outboundGateway` , only one **requestChannel** method, if I set it and set in **coldDrinksFlow** at the same time, it will complain some thing like *only  one return callback can be set on AmqpTemplate*.

Comment: Well, request and reply channel options in XML is just a `channel()` before and after endpoint in Java DSL. You probably talk about a `returnChannel` on the outbound AMQP gateway, but that’s different story.